# How to validate multiple filenames inside string array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string

Inside a string array -"files", 10 file paths are stored.
For example, I show 2 of them,

```
[0] C:\\Users\\17\\Documents\\FS\\D\\mdN_2903.dat
[1] C:\\Users\\17\\Documents\\FS\\D\\mdNBP_29032.dat
```

I want to validate using their filename (before the numbering & extension .dat) as well the number of files counted in c#.net

I tried to use it like this, but it didn't passed even though the files are present

`if(Array.Exists(files,e => e.Contains("mdN_") && e.Contains("mdNBP_") && e.count()==10)) { // All 10 files are present }`

Is there any other way to implement this in c#, please explain?

Comment: What about this: `var okFiles = files.Where(e=> e.Contains("mdN_") && e.Contains("mdNBP_") && e.count()==10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing it. If your file array always has 2 has `mdN` and `mdNBP` and the same order with up to 10 files, you can do something like this:

```
if (files[0].Contains("mdN") && files[1].Contains("mdNBP") && files.Length == 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("all good");
}
```

You can also use linq just example, it can be done differnt ways, here the order does not matter, it just check if you files contian the mentioned values:

```
if (files.Any(e => e.Contains("mdN") && e.Contains("mdNBP") && files.Length == 10))
{
    Console.WriteLine("all good");
}
```

If you have more files, then you can for loop the file array and check against a list of what it should contain.